# Select User type D OR S OR DS from table in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table where User Type is stored as `D`, `S` or both D&S

Like below,

```
ID TYPE
1   D
2   S
3   D
3   S
```

Expected Result:

1. Check user belongs to which type D OR S OR Both.
2. I am expecting 1 for D, 2 for S, and 3 for D&S

I have written below query which is working perfectly fine but I still feel that the query and logic can be implemented in much better way.

```
select case count(distinct TYPE)
          when 2 then 'DS'
          when 1 then (select top 1 TYPE from Table1 )
      end as TYPE
from Table1
```

Logic of above query:

1. Get the count of TYPE of User
2. If `count = 2` then return 'DS'
3. else if `count = 1` then return type of the user (either D or S)

Comment: I m using mssql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need  the type and the number of occurence 
You could do with a group by

```
SELECT type
    ,COUNT(*)
FROM table1
WHERE type IN (
        'D'
        ,'S'
        )
GROUP BY type
```

OR if you need  the number of distinct type and the type

```
SELECT user
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT type)
    ,CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 2
            THEN 'DS'
        ELSE MAX(type)
        END
    ,
FROM table1
WHERE type IN (
        'D'
        ,'S'
        )
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: This query will return 2 records. I need only 1 record for any user that is either D, Or S Or DS.

Comment: please update you question and add  a proper data sample  and the expected  result  ..

Comment: anyway  answer update  with a suggestion for number of distinct type for user

Answer (score 0):

You can use FOR XML PATH as following. I represent your Table1 as a Common table in this script:

```
;With Table1 (ID ,TYPE) as 
(
Select 1 ,  'D'
union
Select 2 ,  'S'
union
Select 3 ,  'D'
union
Select 3 ,  'S'
)


SELECT ID, (
    SELECT  cast(Type as varchar(max))
    FROM Table1 as InnerTable1 
    where InnerTable1.ID = Table1.id
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
from Table1
group by ID
```